# Looking for [intentionally made] vulnerable applications suitable for practicing different penetration techniques (NOT a web apps, user side ones)

Tags: penetration-test, client-side, vulnerability, appsec

I'm looking for different kinds of applications which is intentionnaly (or not) made vulnerable and so are suitable for practicing different penetration techniques, like SQL injections, buffer overflows and such.

There are plenty of similar frameworks designed for praciticing web apps' penetration, DVWA (http://www.dvwa.co.uk/) to name one, (so I don't intrested in these, but you can leave a link or two for other readers, of course), but when it came to user-side, client-server type of applications, I mean, binary/.NET/Java ones - I'd encountered some problems in finding them.

To the day the only one - http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/free-tools/hacmetravel.aspx - got into my list. It's an intentionally made vulnerable .NET application which uses MS SQL db to store its data - perfect example of what I'm searching for.

So, if anyone knows similar educational tools, or just simply a real application, specific build of which is crammed with intresting vulnerabilities, please share this info with me and others. Thanks!

Comment: Metasploitable is an entire OS designed to be suitable for penetration testing. Not an application, but possibly of interest?

Comment: KnightOfNi, thanks, it's a good one, I definetely will dowload and try it, but this one thing bothers me: "Metasploitable is an intentionally vulnerable Linux virtual machine". I would be more intrested in windows applications, as it will be much more probable target in real world pentesting. And I escpecially intrested in client-server apps, like with those using some kind of DB server as their backed, with which they will communicate over the network.

Comment: Have you looked at exploit-db and searched for free apps for which there is known exploits?

Comment: You could have a look at : [OWASP Broken Web Applications](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Broken_Web_Applications_Project). It contains deliberate vulnerable Applications and OpenSource Applications with knowns vulnrabilities.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into CTF problems.  For instance I know [picoCTF](https://picoctf.com/) has a ton of binary exploitation problems, web exploitation challenges, crypto problems, etc.  It's a high school competition (which  actually ended just yesterday), but anyone can create an account and access the problems.  The problems will remain online indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a comprehensive list of websites to practice on which should get you started.

[40+ Intentionally vulnerable websites](https://www.bonkersabouttech.com/security/40-plus-list-of-intentionally-vulnerable-websites-to-practice-your-hacking-skills/392)

Hope that helps,

Baz